# MVC 4 how to add a <div> element conditionally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Want to add a HTML (div) element conditionally. But code exerpt from my Create.cshtml does not work as the parser gets mixed up missing the end-div (the first closing "}" is no code anymore)

```
@if (setDiv)
{
    <div class="@item.DivClass" id="@item.DivId">
}
// More code more HTML
if (setDiv)
{
    </div>
}
```

Anyone an idea how to tackle this problem? Thanks in advance!
Gerard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to encapsulate your opening and closing divs in `@Html.Raw()`. Otherwise razor will not allow this syntax as it does not know that the div that you opened in one if statement is actually closed in another.

```
@if (setDiv)
{
    @Html.Raw("<div class='@item.DivClass' id='@item.DivId'>")
}
// More code more HTML
@if (setDiv)
{
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
```

Comment: Now the class will become textual @item.DivClass, etc. Better is     AT.Html.Raw("<div class=\"" + AT.item.DivClass + "\" id= \"" + AT.item.DivId + "\" ></div>")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if (setDiv)
{
    <div class="@item.DivClass" id="@item.DivId">
}
// More code more HTML
@if (setDiv)
{
   @:</div>
}
```